# how to load file in python numba JIT mode

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba

I am trying to load from files with static content in the @jit function.

but shows Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled, ref following cache1 function

I have also tried using open() but showing following errors (last lines):

```
numba.core.errors.NotDefinedError: Failed in object mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)
The compiler failed to analyze the bytecode. Variable '$54setup_with.1' is not defined.
```

I have also tried to use import, import those data which is written in py file (or compiled as module), ref cache3, showing as not supported

```
Use of unsupported opcode (IMPORT_NAME) found
```

code as follow:

```
@nb.jit()
def cache1(file):
    obj = np.load (file, allow_pickle=True)
    return obj

@nb.jit()
def cache2(file):
enter code here
    with open(file, 'rb') as handle:
        obj = pickle.load(handle)
    handle.close()
    return obj

@nb.jit()
def cache3(file):
    import cache_file_module
    return cache_file_module.data
```

Is there anyway to get this fixed? or any other approach that could let the function read files in jit mode?

Comment: Can you please show some code? I'm getting confused by your description

Comment: I have updated the questions

Comment: Does `numba` say it supports `np.load` or `pickle`? Those don't use Python level iterations, so `numba` might not be able to improve performance.  File read is limited more the OS than `numpy` code.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not yet possible. See https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html . You need to load the file before entering a Numba jit section.

Comment: So, what shall I do? it seems like it is a bottleneck that slows down the performance as I can not have the entire program to be in jit mode as loading file is outside of the jit